# How to solve : Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node/express server code as

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const Room = require("./models/room");
const roomRouter = require("./routes/room");
require("./models/db");
const cors = require("cors");

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

const server = require("http").createServer();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(roomRouter);

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

// const io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world");
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
app.use(cors());

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Connected");

  const id = socket.handshake.query.id;
  socket.join(id);

  socket.on("roomCreated", async (roomId) => {
    console.log("Room created with id of " + roomId);
    const isRoomExist = await Room.findOne({ roomId });
    if (isRoomExist) return;
    const room = await Room({ roomId });
    await room.save();
  });
});

server.on("request", app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("running on 5000");
});
```

I am using socket io and i want to send request from localhost:3000, that's why I needed to allow CORS option. So I wrote the code above. But as soon as I run  the server, it throws me error that says,

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at expressInit (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:30:42)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:323:13)
    at B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
    at next (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at query (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
node:_http_outgoing:576
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:308:21)
    at respond (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\engine.io\build\transports\polling.js:242:22)
    at Polling.doWrite (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\engine.io\build\transports\polling.js:247:13)
    at Polling.write (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\engine.io\build\transports\polling.js:221:14)
    at doWrite (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\engine.io\build\transports\polling.js:203:18)
    at B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\engine.io-parser\build\cjs\index.js:19:17
    at encodePacket (B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\engine.io-parser\build\cjs\encodePacket.js:10:12)
    at B:\projects\typingtestserver\node_modules\engine.io-parser\build\cjs\index.js:16:39 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

P.S. when I open localhost:5000 it is showing "Hello world".

EDITED:

code for roomRouter:

routes/room.js

```
const express = require("express");
const Room = require("../models/room");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/checkId", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("got post request");
  const { roomId } = req.body;
  if (!roomId) res.json({ success: false, message: "No room id typed1" });

  try {
    const room = await Room.findOne({ roomId });

    if (room) res.json({ success: true, message: "Found the room" });
    else res.json({ success: false, message: "Didn't find the room" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: "Error in finding room. Try entering id again",
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

models/room.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    ishost: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    roomId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    players: [PlayerSchema],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Room", RoomSchema
```

);

Comment: Please paste your code for module
`app.use(roomRouter);`

Comment: @Sohan updated.

Comment: On stackoverflow, you should NOT add answers to your question.  Questions should only be for the question.  You can, instead, write your own answer and can even accept it.  That way all good questions here get answered and none are left hanging with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

In index.js file I was using `server.on("request", app)`, and this turned out to be problematic for some reason that I don't know about. Problem is solved after using removing that line and using `const server = require("http").createServer(app);` instead of `const server = require("http").createServer();`